# Changing image of sprite when encountering new level

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

We're trying to make a game in pygame that consists of multiple levels. For a specific level, we want a different sprite/image to be displayed (eg. Level 1 -> girl char, Level 2 -> boat image, Level 3 -> girl char).

We defined a player class in a file called player.py and tried define different players:

```
def __init__(self):

    def player1 (self):
        sprite_sheet1 = SpriteSheet("boat0.png")
        image = sprite_sheet1.get_image(29,165,230,49)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        sprite_sheet2 = SpriteSheet("boat1.png")
        image = sprite_sheet2.get_image(30,168,228,42)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        sprite_sheet3 = SpriteSheet("boat2.png")
        image = sprite_sheet3.get_image(29,165,230,49)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        sprite_sheet2 = SpriteSheet("boat1.png")
        image = sprite_sheet2.get_image(30,168,228,42)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)

    def player2 (self):
        sprite_sheet6 = SpriteSheet("spriteStand.png")
        image = sprite_sheet6.get_image(34, 19, 32, 73)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        sprite_sheet7 = SpriteSheet("spriteWalkL2.png")
        image = sprite_sheet7.get_image(34, 19, 32, 73)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        sprite_sheet8 = SpriteSheet("spriteWalkL1.png")
        image = sprite_sheet8.get_image(34, 19, 32, 73)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        sprite_sheet9 = SpriteSheet("spriteWalkR2.png")
        image = sprite_sheet9.get_image(34, 19, 32, 73)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
        sprite_sheet10 = SpriteSheet("spriteWalkR1.png")
        image = sprite_sheet10.get_image(34, 19, 32, 73)
        self.walking_frames_r.append(image)
```

In a separate file, we tried to call these sprites:

```
class Level_02(Level):

    def __init__(self, player):
         Level.__init__(self, player2)
```

```
class Level_03(Level):

    def __init__(self, player):
        Level.__init__(self, player1)
```

The code doesn't work. How do we get a different image to display for the player sprite depending on what level it's on?

EDIT: more code (`__init__` method for Level class)

```
def __init__(self, player):

    self.platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    self.player = player
```

Comment: What does your `__init__` method look like in your Level class?

Answer (score 0):

`player1` and `player2` are methods that initialize attributes of the `player` object. You need to call these methods:

```py
class Level_02(Level):
    def __init__(self, player):
         player.player2()
         Level.__init__(self, player)
```

```py
class Level_03(Level):
    def __init__(self, player):
        player.player1()
        Level.__init__(self, player)
```